# Restrict (permission) Django staff user from changing certain fields of a model

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, permissions, django-admin

Suppose I have a blog model

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
```

I have a model admin which ensures that which user can change which blog:

```
class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='author').exists()

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='editor').exists() or (request.user.groups.filter(name='author').exists() and Blog.objects.filter(pk=obj, author=request.user).count() >0 )

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name='editor').exists() or (request.user.groups.filter(name='author').exists() and Blog.objects.filter(pk=obj, author=request.user).count() >0 )
```

But I want to restrict a group of user from changing a field of Blog model, say 'author' group can't change the field of author via admin panel.

How can I do that? Thanks in an advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found a way. I can override `save_model` method of `ModelAdmin` and do the following...

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if request.user in permited user:
            obj.save()
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("you can't do that.")
```

Comment: You can also use ``get_readonly_fields()``: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_readonly_fields so to have the UI of the field not modifiable